# Google Translator Consumes memory of browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser, google-translate

I use Google tranlator plugin in my site. My  pages has iframes and therefore I had to add plugin in each frame as they are dynamically update.  But it sounds that the plugin takes much memory. For example, if the site runs on Firefox browser for 5 minutes, Firefox itself increases the memory usage gradually then goes beyond 1gb and finally entire machine gets non responsive. Any one know any reason for this and any solution.

Comment: How much memory are we talking for how many frames? Of course it's going to use *some* memory.

Comment: It is around 3 or 4 frames. The memory consumption goes beyond 1 Gb(Firefox only)